# Is it possible to "share" or "like" something using Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

As title says,

Having some fun with Silverlight and was wondering if liking/sharing something is possible using the forementioned SDK?

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't a limitation of the Facebook C# SDK, but rather a limitation of Facebook's APIs. Facebook does not permit liking via the API. The official like button is the only way to do this. You can create the URL for sharing, but it still requires manual user action.

Comment: could you describe how to "share" then?

Comment: still stuggling with this, could you provide a short sample or a reference?